# How do I remove data after a comma within a column of a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has the below columns

```
df3
    Deposit Name Initial Date 
    22      Gu    03/22/2007 0:00
    30       Pa   09/30/2009 0:00
    11       Ch   1/15/22, 5/11/21
```

the problem is for row 3, I want the initial date only before the comma seperated. So my final df should not have " , 5/11/21".

Im able to manually do this by

```
df3.at[3,'Initial Date']= "1/15/22"
```

But I want a permanent solution so that if there is ever an occurrence in the future where there are more than 1 date under Initiate Date column, then pandas only stores the first date before the comma. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe start with [pandas explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3['Initial Date'].replace(",.*", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you this works. just one minor issue -  the final output dataframe has an additional unnamed column that is created after i execute this line of code. the column just has serial numbers. should i just drop it from the axis?

Comment: @JayJanardhan yes, if you don't need that column....